# Is this dirt under my window still

Tags: walls

In my bathroom under a window. I pulled back wallpaper and found a dirt like substance.
I'm not completely sure what it is. I scrubed it off.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely mould.  You can even see water marks on the wallpaper.  You should look at fixing the water leak first.

Answer (score 0):

It could be mold, but it looks more like soil to me, which was probably brought in by water leakage or insects. Or it's insect feces.

Send it in to a suitable facility for testing. That's the only way to be sure.